# How do I collapse code snippets in SO?

Tags: discussion

Someone posted this example, but I don't know how to do it. Sometimes the code is too long and I wish to collapse it like in this sample:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261082/361159

I cannot find it as a built-in feature in SO.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A month ago, someone edited my code snippet here in stackoverflow and collapse it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605616/3362989

as you can see in stackexchange. I've looked to find the trick but I can't find it, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Whenever you see something here and want to know how it's done, just click on the "edit" link. That gives you the raw source used to generate the post, so you see exactly how it's done. (You don't need to actually submit an "edit"; once you check it out, just back out of the edit screen.)

Comment: In the snippet editor you can find a small checkbox on the left side to hide the sinppet by default

Comment: I don't see it in Chrome or Mozilla, but I've got the answer already. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At the beginning of the snippet, set hide to true, like this:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true -->
```

It will be collapsed by default. Note, though, that if your answer gets downvoted to -3 or lower, this will *completely hide* any trace of the snippet from your answer and just make it look even more downvote-worthy.

Comment: Does it work only on Stack Overflow? I tried this on Super User and nothing happened

Comment: @ChangQian Super User does not have code snippets enabled. Code snippets != code blocks.

Comment: Tried this at the start of a block of text indented with 4 spaces. Didn't work.